# Overiding a .toString method vs looping a .getMethod to print

Tags: java

Had a particular problem with a homework assignment trying to print an array.  I have no specific code...not looking for a specific answer.
It was printing hash code using the print method and consensus is that the .toString() method solves the problem.  I couldnt get this to work but found the second answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19845901/7262393

My question is (if it can be answered generally), why wouldnt I just use a .get() method and loop through all the elements as suggested in this answer?  Is there any particular reason one is used over the other?  I assume the .toString method is a loop that goes and converts each element to a string and then prints them.

Thanks

Comment: Over an array ? Here is the result of `toString()` on a `String[]` with `foo` and `bar` `[Ljava.lang.String;@3e25a5`. So where do you see a loop ?

Comment: `toString()` doesn't loop over an array. The default simply prints the hashcode. But usually when people override the `toString()` in some class, they make it print the object's properties/attributes/fields/global vars.

Comment: Sorry.  Not prints them.  Converts each...maybe im thinking wrong.  Overriding it goes through and converts each.  Its a method right?  So its code must be somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

When using a .get() method to concatenate multiple fields to a String you are going to sacrifice some performance, because for each + operation a new String needs to be created (Java Strings are immutable).

When using a .toString() method you could use something like:

```
String.format("Person {name:%s, street:%s}",name,street);
```

which would have much better performance.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, Apache Commons `ReflectionToStringBuilder` will help you. Please, check this [document](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html) for details.

It can be used in next way:

```
ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(<object you want to print to string>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well which would you rather do every time you want to see the contents of a container object? Loop over it and print each contained item out or call `System.out.println(obj.toString());`?

In general it's better to add `toString()` methods for your classes because that's likely something you are going to want to do a lot when debugging, and it will save you duplicating your effort many times!

Comment: Thanks!  At the moment im handcuffed by the rules of the assignment.  "Dont change your class file" Therefore....looping over it.  I really appreciate all the responses.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you subclass the class and add the `toString()` method, then just use the subclass? (And don't forget to upvote the answers you think are useful! Thanks is nice, but it isn't upvoting :-).)

Comment: You got it.  I was just looking for a reason.  Want to learn why, not just how.  I never remeber anythi g without a reason.

Comment: oops, sorry, forgot that! @Dan dude you need to get some more rep :-P